# AWS SNS Publish sms 'à é è ...' don't work

Tags: java, char, amazon-sns

When i use PublishResult for sending sms, the special chars doesn't works like "éàè ...". And when i use the console of AWS SNS for publish a SMS, sometimes it works and sometimes no ...

If you have any informations about that, can you tell me more informations ?

Comment: Probably an encoding issue - can you show an example?

Comment: For my lastest i use the console of AWS SNS for publish a SMS